# Searching for Q's on SO that are in one of my favorite tags and unanswered

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions, tag-search, tag-watching

I did some looking at the search help and tried out the options but nothing seemed to work. How do I found questions that are unanswered AND IN one of my favorite tags?

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Unanswered tab, scroll down to you Favorite tags section, then click on the tag.  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java

If you want to see questions that have zero answers (as opposed to questions with no upvoted answers, which is what you get on the Unanswered tab) then you can use "answers:0" in the search box.  Example: [`answers:0 [java]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+[java])

Comment: So is there no way to view unanswered questions that occur in any of my favorite tags? I don't want to target a single tag at a time. I want to see all unanswered Q's in any/all of my favorite tags.

Comment: @HK1: Yeah, if you click the Unanswered button there are four tabs at the top right.  Click the "my tags" tab. http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. It does appear that the questions listed there actually do have answers, for the most part. Probably 95% of them already have answers.